# Thunderbird is not authenticating Gmail Account on 19.04 but works well with other Ubuntu Distros

Tags: 19.04, thunderbird

After I updated my password on my Gmail account I can no longer get Thunderbird to authenticate. The pop up comes up and saves “allow thunderbird to access…” when I click “allow” I get a quick error message that Thunderbird was not able to authenticate. This is very frustrating. I am able to authenticate TB for my Gmail account with the new password on all my other devices but my Ubuntu 19.04 will not do it. I am able to see the web page for this account with no problems. I have been trying to do everything I can think of and everything others are saying to no avail. I have been using TB exclusively on my Linux machine for many years with no problem. I threw away the saved password from Chrome and now the new password shows up in the saved passwords in TB but no luck authenticating.

Comment: IMAP or POP? What Google servers are you using. What ports? What security? In Firefox, go to https://www.google.com. Locate your face icon in the top right corner of the screen. Select "Sign out of all accounts". Then select the Google account where you updated the password. It may ask for your new password. After you get in, retry TB.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, i had to download the new version from https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/ then it worked, except it is not a proper installation that is merged with the system. You have an icon on the desktop but not integrated. So I cant make a launcher icon in the panels.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, i had to download the new version from https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/ then it worked, except it is not a proper installation that is merged with the system. You have an icon on the desktop but not integrated. So I cant make a launcher icon in the panels.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux
It seems the older versions are not updating and the older versions don't like Google mail, I had the same problem at work on a windows machine. I had to download the new version manually as it didn't update automatically.

Comment: Yes, now it worked for me. Thanks